# How can I find an app named "." to possibly uninstall it?

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to upgrade my Windows 10 machine. I keep getting a message about needing to uninstall an app that is simply named `.` or perhaps it is a bullet:

[image: Image saying "We couldn't uninstall these apps. You'll need to remove these apps yourself, and then select Refresh. These programs need to be uninstalled because they aren't compatible with the upgrade." Then following this is the "list" which is a single dot. It is not obvious if it is a period or a bullet or something else, but it could be a period.]

I don't see any app with this name. On Linux, I would expect `.` to simply refer to the current directory. Perhaps this is a permissions issue? I have installed Linux tools previously, but uninstalled them in preparation for this "Feature update to Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1607."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That appears to be a bullet point which would list the apps that are unable to be uninstalled.

It appears to have been discussed with a solution here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/blank-uninstall-this-app-now-because-it-isnt/5799ff77-ae7e-4947-abf7-8a7b19769a5f

> Open the hidden folder, `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\`
>
> Then, go to `Sources\Panther\` subfolder. Sort files by date.
>
> Find file named `<some symbols>_APPRAISER_HumanReadable.xml`
>
> Open it in Notepad. This is setup log in XML format.
>
> Search the string: `<Property Name="DT_ANY_FMC_BlockingApplication"
>   Value="TRUE"`.
>
> This string is located in Property list "Decision Maker" XML-section.
>
> Look some strings up, there should be XML-value of the "Asset"
>   XML-property.
>
> In "Property-List Type Inventory" section you can find the program
>   path ("lower case long path" XML-attribute).
>
> Uninstall this program, and run setup again.
>
> Repeat these steps, for all founded strings with
>   `BlockingApplication=True` value.

Comment: Perfectly what I needed!